# ThreeJS camera is not looking at the object from the top

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I am repositing camera with object position, 
but the camera is not looking at the object from the top . How can i make this ?

```
const box = new THREE.Box3();
box.expandByObject(this.object);
const center = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

this.controls.minDistance = center.y + 1;

this.controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(
    this.threeDisplayPoint.x,
    this.threeDisplayPoint.y,
    this.threeDisplayPoint.z
);
this.tl = new TimelineMax();
this.tl.to(this.camera.position, 0.8, {
    ...center,
    y: center.y+1,
    ease: Expo.easeOut
});
```

I want this;
[image]

My code is working like this
[image]

How can i make this?

Comment: Does it help if you call `this.controls.update()` after setting the `target` property?

Comment: I don't have a problem with updating controls. Controls is updating.

Comment: So you are calling `update()` in your animation loop? Sry for asking, but this is not obvious from your code snippet.

Comment: Please demonstrate your issue with a fiddle. It seems to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/mnuk20f8/